# dynamically created Buttons overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, button, dynamically-generated

I have created a layout with a `database` call where a `button` will be created for each item inside the `database`. The `buttons` are created like I need and I also found out, how to set up the `layout_width` and `layout_height` but all `buttons` are placed in the same position and overlap each other so that only the last created `button` can be accessed. My code for creating the `buttons` looks like this:

```
Button bt = new Button(this);
bt.setText("Button Title");
bt.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linerLayout.addView(bt);
```

The activity looks like that, after generating the buttons:

[image: Overlapping buttons]

I looked at each method that can be used for the button but didn't find anything to define the position. I just thought about following method:

```
bt.layout(l, t, r, b);
```

but don't know exactly how to use it and thought there might be a simpler method to solve this problem. Anybody who knows a workaround?!

---

### CHANGED CODE

I just tryied to set the layout parameters like explained from "Chen doron". I have a relative layout inside my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/llActOver"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" >        
</RelativeLayout>
```

and formatted the generated buttons like this:

```
Button bt = new Button(context);
bt.setText(c.getString(iDef));
fontClass.setFont(bt);
//RelativeLayout placeholder = new RelativeLayout(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  layoutParam = 
           new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
if(rowCount < 1){
    layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    rowCount++;
}else{
    layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, lastButtonId);
}

lastButtonId = bt.getId();
//placeholder.addView(bt, layoutParam);
        
linearLayout.addView(bt, layoutParam);
```

I save the buttons id at the end of the loop so that the last buttons id can be accessed in the next round.
I also tryied to create a new relativ layout for each new button like the commented part of the code shows but even without the new layout nothing happens and i still just have all buttons overlapped.

Comment: Try this :-

This [link][1] might help to you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869197/android-creating-button-dynamically-and-fill-layout

Comment: I looked at the hole post and couldn't find the solution... also looked at a long presentation from devoxx about Layouts http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2191&sl=3.... but nothing to find...maybe you can give me a hint if you know where I have to look exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, but just by trying each possible combination of layout types.
I found out, i have to define a LinearLayout inside the XML file and the attribute android:orientation="vertical" is affordable. all the other parameters that have been set before were unimportant.

So now i have a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView in my xml file:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llActOver"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and inside the java database i have following code to create a button for each row in the db, setting its Text and Font and add it to the loaded layout:

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

    Button bt = new Button(context);
    bt.setText(c.getString(iDef));
    fontClass.setFont(bt);
    linearLayout.addView(bt);
}
```

and here a screenshot of the result:

[image]

maybe somebody else who has the same problem won't need to worry as long as me with this description.

Comment: how to do it with relative layout?

Comment: I've never tried it with `RelativeLayout` but maybe you try it with @Chen Doron answer.

Comment: **I've never tried it with RelativeLayout**.. It's in the question  you posted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried it, but I didn't get it work. Only with LinearLayout. Maybe I forgot some parameters inside the xml and thatfore it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Relative Layout, and have the first Button align to the parent's top.
Then each button aligned to the previous button's bottom.

Use:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```

And then:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,ID-Of-Previous-Button);
```

Also check out:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: like you can see, i tried it the way you showed me but it didn't change the view. I inserted my changed code in my post above

Comment: I edited my answer.
must have been tired when I first wrote it.

You need this line.
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,ID-Of-Previous-Button);
"BELOW" instead of "ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_TOP".

Also, when inserting views programmatically, you need to set the ID's  that you're aligning relatively to.

Comment: I just tried this type of parameter but the buttons also doesn't fit my layout again. I will try some other combinations to solve this problem but maybe somebody knows the solution. And I just wanted to mention that the parameter is called "ALIGN_PARENT_TOP" and not "ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_TOP".