# How to make 100 buttons in android studio without xml file?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm searching for a code that it doesn't need a long .xml and I can easily change number of buttons too 200 or everything.

```
public class buttons extends Activity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buttons);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to dynamically creating the buttons and adding them to layout

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8904214/6468767

Comment: May we know the reason of having 100 buttons?

Comment: I want to have every number of buttons ... 100 is just an example

Answer (score 0):

in activity file add this:

```
    // create buttons in a loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Button " + i);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
public class Buttons extends Activity {
{

Button button;
List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
LinearLayout list;
OnClickListener listener;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.long);

params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);

listener = new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

int id = v.getId();
Button b = buttonList.get(id);
///

}
};

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
addButton();

}


public void addButton()
{
button = new CheckBox(this);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
button.setText("TEXT");
button.setId(buttonList.size());
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
buttonList.add(button);
list.addView(button);
}
}
```

Comment: what is list ?? in findviewbyid(). its cant find the symbol list !!

Comment: This layout, in which are placed the buttons